# Openshift cron doesn't run php file

Tags: php, cron, openshift

I have 2 .php files in my application - book.php and weather.php. I create a file named "runscript" in /.openshift/cron/minutely. This file contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

php -f $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/weather.php
```

This script send me message to phone every minute, it's OK.
Then I replace to:

```
php -f $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/book.php
```

This script MUST send me message too, but nothing is happing. But if I just run this script by my webbrowser (go to the http://xxx-xxxxxxx.rhcloud.com/book.php) so I got my message. How is it possible? Magic?

Comment: Are you sure you have installed cron cartridge?

Comment: Ok guys, thanks for your answers. I added in the end of book.php code that write log file and it works fine. But first part of code doesn't work. This part must write some text on some site. If I run it with browser - it writes. If it run with cron - doesn't write. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Did you miss the `#!/bin/bash` part? That's needed to run the shell script.

Answer (score 0):

For why your cron job is not executing, check the cron logs on OpenShift. You can find them at `~/app-root/logs/cron_*.log` when you SSH into your gear.

Make sure your cron job is execuable with `chmod`, and has the shebang line as @gnaanaa says. Also check if you have one of the `.openshift/cron/minutely/jobs.{allow,deny}` files as they may cause cron to skip your job. (See the [cron README](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-php-openshift-quickstart/blob/master/.openshift/cron/README.cron) for more information.)

And after your cron job is working, you can get rid of the wrapper script `runscript` and have cron call `book.php` directly. To do so, place `book.php` directly into `.openshift/cron/minutely`, make it executable, and add this shebang to it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I use openshift aswell and executed a php file with a cron aswell.

```
#!/bin/bash
php ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}index.php
```

This executes the script normally at first sight. However no output was produced. The problem was, that all the required php files couldnt be loaded because the working directory was not the same as it would be when loaded by the webserver. Setting the working directoy in the php script itself will prevent this error and makes the script perfectly executable by the cron.

This should help some people to get their script running.